# What is the meaning of maximum possible restriction of domain for a function’s inverse to be a function

Tags: definition, inverse-function

A question in a maths assignment has a question which asks for “the maximum possible restriction of the domain of f(x) so that it’s inverse will also be a function”. I can’t quite understand what the question is asking from it’s wording. Here is a picture of the whole question:
[image]
Could anyone clarify for me?

Comment: Can you identify $f^{-1}$?  Do you know what makes it not a function?

Comment: Yeah, I get that I have to restrict the domain, so that when flipped across y=x, a vertical line along any part of the graph will only pass through one point. However, I don’t understand the wording of how it wants me to restrict the domain. What does the question mean by “maximum”?

Comment: For example, define $f(x)=x^2$.  If we restrict the function $f:[0,\infty)$, then its inverse will also be a function.

Comment: I think they mean the *least* possible restriction. This will then give the maximum possible range for the inverse.

Comment: For $f(x)=x^2$, if we restrict it to $(-\infty,0]$, the inverse is also a function. You could also use $[-1,0] \cup (1,\infty)$,a.s.o. From the overall question, I guess they are after either "side" of the parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Once you put the quadratic into the given form, you will be able to find the line of symmetry, which is given by $x=b.$ Then the function will be injective on either $(-\infty,b]$ or in $[b,+\infty).$ Either ones of these will serve as the *least restriction* of the domain to give the maximum range for the inverse.

Hope this helps.